# What are these lines on the fuselage of a 747?

Tags: boeing-747, fuselage

Have a look at this picture:                                                  [image]

It's from [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/KLM---Royal/Boeing-747-406/2805594/L/) (though I've modified it a lot) and shows some lines on the fuselage. What are they? Are they Lightning Diverter Strips like in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25020/what-are-these-lines-on-the-nose-of-a-boeing-737) ?

Comment: aren't they just edges?

Comment: Duplicate? [Why are these rivets on the 777 so visible?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26777/why-are-these-rivets-on-the-777-so-visible)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, they are just the boundaries between skin panels. See below for a picture of the 747-8 fuselage during assembly.

[[image: Boeing 747-8 front from side[1]]

Boeing 747-8 front from side (picture [source](http://www.cnet.com/pictures/where-boeings-next-gen-747-8-comes-to-life-photos/13/))

And this is how the panels for the cylindrical section look like before they are joined:

[image: Boeing 747-8 panel skins]

Boeing 747-8 fuselage panels. The original picture ([source](http://www.cnet.com/pictures/where-boeings-next-gen-747-8-comes-to-life-photos/34/)) is named "wing panel skins", but these are really fuselage parts.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are skin laps. The vertical ones do not overlap, the horizontal laps overlap by three rows of fasteners.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine but it would probably help if you explained what a "skin lap" is. The asker surely wanted to understand what they _are_, not just what their name is.